# SSDT 2015 custom package templates

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to use some of my existing packages as templates for new package and I can see them fine and create new package fine except for two issues. I do understand there may not be a fix for these, just thought I would ask in case I am missing something.

1. If I 'Add New Item' select my template package and enter a new name, this new name is not updated in the package itself. For instance the variables are all scoped to the original template name
2. When using my package template in new projects, there is always an error with connection managers. I think I understand that the GUID is used in the package and would change on a new package but I was hoping if I had a connection manager of the same name in the new project it would just pick it up.

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for feedback Mat, not sure what else I could add or another way to frame question. Maybe this isn't the best forum for this type of question.

Comment: @SteveDingle you can do at least screenshots

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - I suppose I could however not sure that would add any more than the text. I now don't think this is the best type of question for this forum. It isn't a 'how do I do'  or type question, its about how the SSDT 'add new item' process deals with custom templates. I think it belongs on more SSIS/SSDT focused forums. Thanks again for your suggestion, I will remember all comments for my next post.

Comment: @SteveDingle there are a lot of people with the advanced knowledge about SSDT and SSIS here. 2 people said to you already that your question is very unclear and if you'll put that question to another forum, you'll probably get the same comments.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - point taken, guess i am not a very good 'question asker' :-(. Can't be good at everything. Thanks again and happy holidays.